# Removing a 'b' from the Python String

Tags: python, numpy

I am currently using the `Numpy` package (version 1.12.1) in `Spyder` (`Python 3.6`).
For some reason I am unable to remove `'b's` which appear before strings in the `IPython` Console.

```
   import numpy as np

   student = np.dtype([('name', 'S20'), ('age', 'i1'), ('code', 'i4')])
   print (student)

   recordsvar = np.array([('Cordelia',28,100),('Cordelia',29,101),
   ('Cordelia',30,102)], dtype=student)
   print (recordsvar)
```

The output is

```
[(b'Cordelia', 28, 100) (b'Cordelia', 29, 101) (b'Cordelia', 30, 102)]
```

How do I remove the 'b' in from of Cordelia?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hmm, actually maybe not a duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `b'` indicates, that your data is stored as bytes, the numpy datatype is `S20`. If you want to store characters, use unicode as datatype: `U20`:

```
student = np.dtype([('name', 'U20'), ('age', 'i1'), ('code', 'i4')])
```

Comment: Apologies. I didn't realise I had forgotten to accept it. Thanks for reminding me.